# How to Stop a Backslash in appSetting.config Being Doubled

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am new to Devops in general and am struggling to get a stage of my CI/CD Pipeline in Azure Devops to work correctly.

This is a full YAML CI/CD in the Pipelines section. I have not used the Classic mode in the Releases section.

I have the connection string saved as a Secret (Also tested with standard variable) Pipeline Variable Name of ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection and a Value of `Server=(localdb)\UK;Database=CustomerPortal;User ID =User;Password=SomePassword;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true`

In my YAML I have tried:

```
- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'IIS Web App Deploy'
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: '$(CurrentStagingSite)'
    Package: '$(Parameters.Package)'
    XmlVariableSubstitution: true
    JSONFiles: '**/appSettings.json'
```

And:

```
- task: FileTransform@1
  displayName: 'File Transform: '
  inputs:
    fileType: json
    targetFiles: '**/appSettings.json'
    folderPath: '$(Parameters.Package)'
```

Both have worked and substituted the Connection String from the variable to the appSetting.config JSON but the final package uploaded to the Website Location on the server contains this:

[image: Connection String]

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\UK;Database=CustomerPortal;User ID=User;Password=SomePassword;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
```

I am clearly doing something wrong or misunderstanding something, how do I stop the Transform from making it \\?

Comment: This is just escape character. Did you notice wrong behavior of the app with `\\\`?

Comment: Yes, the app doesnt like the (localdb)\\UK in the connection string within the appSettings.config. If I manually update the appSetting.config to (localdb)\UK, then the app works as expected

Comment: @Shushud did You solved problem? I have this same issue. What is strange here for us connection to DB stopped working few days ago, but this small app was deployed month ago and was working with double "\\".

One of solutions is to use port instead of instance name - each instance have separate port so You can have it like this:  "Server=(localdb),1434"

But for us this is not solution - I want get rid of double "\\"